# MySQL 5 default null for date, cannot insert date = '' why?

Tags: mysql, date, asp-classic

I have created the following table, I set the dates to DEFAULT NULL. But when I try to insert an empty string into the table. I will get an error. What is the best way to treat empty field to insert into dates?

```
CREATE TABLE `testing` (
  `AUTOINC` double NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TST` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE 
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `EMP_CODE` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DT_JOIN` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `DT_CONFIRM` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `DT_RESIGN` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_ID` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DATETIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AUTOINC`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=126 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


insert into TMEMPLY (EMP_CODE,DT_JOIN,DT_CONFIRM,DT_RESIGN,USER_ID,DATETIME)
values ('TEST','2017-09-19','','','BRO','2017-09-19 14:47:21')
```

The error

```
Incorrect date value: '' for column 'DT_CONFIRM'
```

How do I treat empty field for dates. For example, if user don't input and leave an empty field for dates in a form. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, `datetime` column accept a valid date or a `null` value. So instead of passing `''` (blank), pass `null` here, as you already know `''` is not equals to `null`. So the query is something like:

```
insert into TMEMPLY (EMP_CODE,DT_JOIN,DT_CONFIRM,DT_RESIGN,USER_ID,DATETIME)
values ('TEST','2017-09-19', null, null,'BRO','2017-09-19 14:47:21')
```